# Routing to game folder in public folder

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm making a website with an integrated game. I placed the game (inside a folder)  in the root of the laravel project.

I want the route to be 'mywebsite.com/game', but redirect it to 'mywebsite.com/game/index.php'. But I only want the url to show '/game'.

My controller

```
// GAME
Route::get('/game', 'HomeController@game');
```

Controller:

```
public function game()
{
    return Redirect::to('/game/index.php');
}
```

But when I do that, I get 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' when browsing to '/game'. It looks like it doesn't redirects to 'index.php' like I intend to in my controller.

Am I using `Redirect::to` wrong because it's not a laravel view? Or is it something else?

Comment: Your redirect to `/game` is being routed to when you try to go to `/game/index.php` because it starts with `/game`.  Try putting your game in a different path like `/my-game` or something like that

Comment: @SebBarre, indeed that solves the error and I can reach the game. But now my url still shows '/game/index.php'. Any way I can solve that too?

Comment: You can solve that with a webserver-level redirect.  It sounds like your game is outside of Laravel so you can't use the routing in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an .htaccess with a RewriteRule for that.